# LCD Display hangs the computer

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, lcd, osx

I'm trying to connect 16x2 LCD screen to clone Arduino UNO via PF8574T backpack. 4 cables are connected to +5V, GND, SDA and SDL pins.

<strike>When I tried [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner?action=sourceblock&num=1) I2C scanner code from arduino.cc. It returned strange characters in serial monitor at first couple of tries. And now, when I try computer hangs.</strike>

When I use A4 A5 pins on the Arduino instead of SDA and SDL, i2c reported the device is on 0x27. It is ok. But if i keep LCD connected to Arduino, my iMac shutdowns after for a while. In error log i see there was a problem regarding USB serial device. I assume it as a power problem.

I'm on OS X Yosemite. Why this can be happening and how can I fix?

Note: Computer is hanging as soon as the Arduino usb cable connected.

Comment: Update: When I removed the LCD, the it connected without error so I could delete I2C scanner sketch.

Comment: Update2: I have updated my question. It seems as a power problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes my system hangs in the way you describe  ("hanging as soon as the Arduino usb cable connected")  if I mistakenly connect  the +ve and -ve supply lines to an i2c device the wrong way round.

Comment: It seems there is short in the backback circuit. Or may be the pin markings are wrong.